# Como transferir uma tabela da área de transferência para um data.frame do R

Tags: r

### Motivação

Em várias perguntas da linguarem`R`vejo as pessoas colocando o conteúdo de uma tabela no lugar de mostrar os passos para reproduzir os dados que elas estão analizando. Pedidos de fornecer o resultado do comando `dput` são simplesmente ignorados.

Ter que digitar algo como

```
dados <- data.frame(carat = c(0.230, 0.210) ...)
```

a todo o momento é tedioso, sujeito a erros e um desperdício de tempo.

### Pergunta

Como faço para transferir os dados da tabela abaixo para um `data.frame` usando a área de transferência? O famoso `Ctr-v`

```
 carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
 0.230 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5  55.0   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
 0.210 Premium   E     SI1      59.8  61.0   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
 0.230 Good      E     VS1      56.9  65.0   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4  58.0   334  4.20  4.23  2.63
 0.310 Good      J     SI2      63.3  58.0   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
 0.220 Fair      E     VS2      65.1  61.0   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que há um problema de plataforma para importar dados com o `ctr-v`, então aqui vão duas opções:

**Para usuários do Windows**:

Você pode usar a função `readClipboard()` para vetores. Por exemplo, entrar os dados somente de uma linha ou coluna de um data frame.

Para dados tabulares, simplesmente use a função `read.table()` com `clipboard` como nome do arquivo:

```
read.table(file = "clipboard", head = TRUE)
```

**Outros sistemas**:

Eu recomendo a função `read.clipboard()` do pacote `psych`:

```
psych::read.clipboard(head = TRUE)
```

Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://www.personality-project.org/r/html/read.clipboard.html) para mais funções do pacote.

Comment: Acabei de testar. `read.table(file = "clipboard", head = TRUE)` também funciona no linux.